# Link(a tag) created by innerHTML can't load it's href file in jQuery slide Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="dev-jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slidepanel.js">
        </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.slidepanel.css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel({
    orientation: 'right',
    mode: 'overlay'
    });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        function init()
        {
         document.getElementById("link23").innerHTML+='<br/><a href="slide.html" data-slidepanel="panel2" style="float:\'left\'">Show Panel2</a>';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div>
        <div>
            Hello how are you 
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="slide.html" data-slidepanel="panel" style="float:'left'">Show Panel</a>
        </div>  
            <div id='link23'>
            <h3>Problematic DIV</h3>
            Hello... all... The link/anchor tag here in this div is created by Javascript's init() function.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My project is in core php. My project's need is such that, based on javascript function I want to create a list of clickable DIVs (displaying information about parameters) on the right side of a web-page. I want these clickable DIV (when clicked), open/hide **jQuery slide/popup window** which shall display more information of the link clicked. So I searched on Internet and found "jQuery Slide Panel 2.0" from GITHUB and I felt it suitable. Now, to create links dynamically on right side of my page I use getElementById() function and append the HTML to it by innerHTML() function. I have shown here the test code only. In this code, the first link(a tag) is created statically whereas the next LINK(a tag) is created by js's init() function. The problem is that the First link (created statically) is able to load it's href="**myfile.html**" in jQuery slide panel but the Second link (created by JavaScript) can not load it's href="***myfile2.html***" in jQuery slide panel. Instead the second link navigates to **"myfile2.html"** which I don't want. Please help me solve this issue. I might have made a silly mistake or it might be a problem of JS. I have been stucked in this problem for last 10 days.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or at least a link to the plugin.

Comment: https://codeload.github.com/egdelwonk/SlidePanel/zip/2.0 this is the url from which I have downloaded the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

In the case above it could be sufficient to call slidepanel after you have added all elements you want attach.

**Old answer, valid for a more general case where elements that need the plugin are created later**

The plugin has very poor [documentation](http://codebomber.com/jquery/slidepanel/), however looking at the source code we can find that the plugin doesn't automatically attach elements looking at their attributes (and this behaviour is fine).
You have to explicitly attach the plugin to each element that requires it.
Also be careful since the plugin doesn't check if it is already attached to an element.
You have many alternatives, the quickest is to add the following code just after you push the new link:

```
$('[data-slidepanel="panel2"]').slidepanel({
  orientation: 'right',
  mode: 'overlay'
});
```

However I recomend to create the new link through jQuery instead of directly pushing the html code, this way you avoid the need of unique selectors to find the element, you could do it this way:

```
var newLink = $('<a href="slide.html" ...>...</a>'); //Don't put <br/> in newLink!
newLink.slidepanel(...);
$('#link23').append($('<br/>')); //<br/> goes here
$('#link23').append(newLink);
```

Comment: I have changed my code as per your suggestion and it works fine. Thank you very much. Actually the problem was not that but DOM elements created after calling jQuery were out of scope. So it was not responding.. Thanks.. Now working.